# Dynamically add QWebEngineView to layout

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm trying to dynamically QWebEngineView to already existing layout.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QWebEngineView view;
    view.setUrl(QUrl(QStringLiteral("http://www.qt.io")));
    view.resize(1024, 750);
    view.show();
    ui->splitter->addWidget(view);  
}
```

When running this i'm getting `error: C2664: 'void QSplitter::addWidget(QWidget *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'QWebEngineView' to 'QWidget *'`

I'm trying to create program for previewing and editing html/text/image files in local file system. This means that i need to switch widget in main window for different tasks. In my designer form I have splitter layout in which I'm trying to add QWebEngineView.

I tried default examples from Qt Designer for WebEngine and WebKit. They work just as planned but instead of using UI layout they are using only code for adding and managing widgets. I want to use form layouts, which means that this option is not suited for me.

How i can fix this issue ?
Is this viable solution for what i'm trying to achieve or there is a better one ?

Comment: can't convert from an instance to a pointer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QWebEngineView *view;
    view = new QWebEngineView(this);
    view->setUrl(QUrl(QStringLiteral("http://www.qt.io")));
    view->resize(1024, 750);
    view->show();
    ui->splitter->addWidget(view);  
}
```